# How to change file URI string

Tags: android

How to change something `file:///system/media/lockscreen/lockscreen_001.jpg` to 
something like `/mnt/sdcard/myPicture.jpg`
The reason why I want to change is that file:/// is wrong if I want to further process. It is hard to tell but if I get the `URI` from `Uri uri= data.getData();` is `file:///system/media/lockscreen/lockscreen_001.jpg`, how to handle because normally is start with `mnt`

Comment: Are you using `camera` or `gallery` to select image to use?

Comment: gallery, and camera is fine, just gallery not ok

Comment: I have posted solution below. Try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///system/media/lockscreen/lockscreen_001.jpg");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+uri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

`uri.getPath()` will give you the path by eliminating `file:` extension.

**EDIT :**

```
Uri urinew = Uri.parse(uri.getPath());
```

This will give you new uri with the path you got.

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: after getPath(), it return /system/media/lockscreen/lockscreen_001.jpg

Comment: but uri.getPath() will return String, how to return back to URI??

Comment: @jjLin See the edit post I have made. That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code can help you :

```
Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
```